# Vimeo bulk upload and mysql match

Tags: php, mysql, vimeo, vimeo-api

I would like to know if on Vimeo PRO account i can use any method to store some info about a video in MySQL DB and match them with upload video.

The easiest thing i can guess is rename the video file with a random token and store it in my DB as primary key with video associated info, copy to dropbox the video and upload it.

But, as far as i know, it seems that uploaded video gets renamed,

I also need to do this in bulk on 2.000 videos.

Comment: I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [redit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: sorry but did not know reddit could be a good starting point for this kind of things

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo assigns each video a unique videoId. You can make a GET request to their API and pull a list of all videos with data on them. I built something similar.

We pull the video information and stored it in a table and used that table to populate a grid with the video data for a user to edit. Its described here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#/{video_id}

Also check their vimeo google group for more information.